# Pass mutiple values with a href button

Tags: codeigniter

```
<button class="btn btn-outline-primary">
   <a href="<?php echo $trans['id'];?>">OK</a>
 </button>
```

Here is my a href button code.I want to pass more values like name,code with id to controller.How can i pass it?.I'm a codeigniter beginner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<button class="btn btn-outline-primary">
   <a href="<?php echo $trans['id'];?>/<?php echo $trans['name'];?>/<?php echo $trans['code'];?>">OK</a>
 </button>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can pass multiple variables with the **anchor tag** easily

```
<button class="btn btn-outline-primary">
   <a href="<?= base_url('controller_name/function_name/'.$variables1.'/'.$variable2.'/'.$variable3)?>">OK</a>
 </button>
```

In the controller values will be get like this

```
public function function_name($variable1, $variable2, $variable3){
    echo $variable1;
    echo $variable2; 
    echo $variable3;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it this way too.

```
<button class="btn btn-outline-primary">
    <a href="<?php echo $trans['id'] . '/' . $trans['name'] . '/' . $trans['code'];?>">OK</a>
</button>
```